# 301 redirect all ugly permalinks from old site to new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

So I overhauled a  complete website the other day and found some of the old pages snippets in the google search results. The old page had an ugly link structure such as `domain.com/index.php?article_id=123`. The new site uses pretty permalinks such as `domain.com/pagetitle`.

Is there a piece of code I could put into the .htaccess file in order to redirect all ugly permalinks to the new site?

**Edit**

Additional info: The old links don't exist anymore. The old site and the new one's structure differs a lot, not all contents from the all site were adapted. Main problem is that I don't want the old links in the google search results to always throw a 404 at the user.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to know?

Comment: I wasn't asking about those two links in particular. I wonder if there would be a snippet for .htaccess that fetches all those ugly permalinks (with a structure like `domain.com/index.php?article_id=123`) and redirects them to the new site (which is using `domain.com/pagetitle` permalink structure)

Comment: Right, those would be two different pages with different contents. The page structure and the contents were not adapted for the new page and we don't want the old links in the google search results to always throw a 404 to the user. The old links don't exist any more. I edited that to my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something of a

RedirectMatch ^/index.php?$  http://www.example.com/somepage

This will redirect all pages starting from index.php to another location

Comment: Using this method means that my new site does not lose the seo-juice from the old site, right?

Comment: We've done such thing as our SEO told us.. Better of course not to redirect them all to one page, but redirect to relevant pages, that would be best way. Or you can write personal redirects for some prominent old pages and redirect others by RedirectMatch

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment on the other answer, but that is a very improper solution if you value your SEO at all. A redirect is your way of telling Google "I've got the same page, I just moved it". There's a much better way to do this that won't negatively affect your SEO at all.

You should create some logic to redirect those old links to your new links.

Here's an example of how you could do it:

1. Go to the beginning of your program, before any logic takes place.
2. Use code to retrieve the requested page. In this case, you might be able to get away with simply checking for GET variables that match article_id.
3. If the requested page is a match for your GET variable, run a query to see if the article exists. (Obviously, you'll still want to 404 articles that don't exist).
4. Retrieve the content used to generate the new, more SEO-friendly URL's. This is probably the article title or something.
5. Write some code to generate the new article title. At this point, if this is working properly, you should be able to system print that new URL to make sure it's correct.
6. 301 redirect to the new URL. Don't 302 or any other number, 301 redirect it. This lets search engines know it's the same page and content, but it has permanently moved.

Comment: Does 2. and 3. result in 301 redirecting those URLs to matching content on the new site? I'm asking because the contents and structure of the new site differs a lot from the old one, which is already off the grid. Would you mind assisting with an example? Let's say we have article_id=123 which has no matching content on the new site and article_id=345 with matching content at url.com/matching-content. I'd appreciate you helping me wrap my head around that. Sorry for bad formatting (I'm on m phone).

Comment: @okiedokey Yes, you would 301 redirect the old article_id=345 to the /new-article. To answer what you should do if article_id=123 where there's no matching content. then you would want to 404 that page.